# Can the differential equation $ (2xy+2x)dx -ydy =0 $ be solved using this method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My first DiffEq exam was yesterday and one of the questions we had in that exam was this:

$$ (2xy \; + \; 2x)dx  \; -ydy =0 $$

What I did was I multiplied $dx$ by both terms in between the brackets, then took: $$ 2xdx \; -ydy = 0 $$ and solved it  as: $$ x^2 - \; \frac {y^2}2 = C $$
then solved the first term $ \int 2xy \; dx $ and in the end I got: $$ x^2y + x^2 - \frac {y^2}2 = C $$

is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get rid of the term $2xydx$, to reintegrate it later on? This step is so creative that it is squarely wrong. Instead, note that $$2xdx=\frac{y}{y+1}dy$$

Comment: @Did I read about it on the "Integrating factors" chapter in tenenbaum's ODE book, he did something similar in page 99 example 12.11 . You're right I should've recognized that eq as seperable but I dont know what was wrong with me during the exam :(

Comment: In exams one gets nervous to forget a term $2xy\,dx$ altogether.

Comment: @EdgyLord : What you did isn't correct. You are not allowed to separate the ODE in two parts which are not exact and integrate each one separately. Moreover $\int 2xydx\neq x^2y$ because $y$ isn't constant. Probably you misunderstood the method shown in the book.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y}{y+1}dy=2xdx$$
$$(1-\frac{1}{y+1})dy=2xdx$$
integrate both sides
$$y-\log|y+1|=x^2+C$$

Answer (score 0):

You missed it when you tried to solve the terms separately like that.

The solution is not too hard:  The equation is
$$
2x(y+1)dx = y\,dy
$$
which makes it natural to use $v = y+1$ whence $dy = dv$ and 
$$2x\,dx = (1-\frac1v) dv \\
x^2 = V - \log v +K \\
x = \sqrt{y+(K+1) - \log(y+1)} = \sqrt{y+C - \log(y+1)} 
$$

and you then do the other important step missed, which is checking that this satisfies the differential equation (it does).

By the way, I don't think you want to naively place $\log|1+y|$ in the answer, but if you check in the original differential equation, it comes out right because when $v<0$, $$\frac{d}{dv}(\log(-v)) = +\frac1v$$  To be more precise, there are solutions valid for $y<-1$ but you must have$C = R + i\pi$ where $R$ is a real constant; you can then  use that imaginary part to turn the log into the log of an absolute value.

Also, as pointed out by J. Jaquelin, either sign of the square root does satisfy the equation. So...
$$x = \pm\left|\sqrt{y+C - \log(|y+1|)} \right|
$$

Comment: You should put absolute values in the $log$ and $\pm$ behind the square roots.

Comment: You are right.  The absolute value part is a bit subtle.